# Python piecewise function interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i am trying to construct a function which gives me interpolated values of a piecewise linear function. I tried linear spline interpolation (which should be able to do exactly this?)- but without any luck. The problem is most visible on a log scale plot. Below there is the code of a small example i prepared:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy import interpolate

#Original Data
pwl_data = np.array([[0,1e3, 1e5, 1e8], [-90,-90, -90, -130]])

#spine interpolation
pwl_spline = interpolate.splrep(pwl_data[0], pwl_data[1])

spline_x = np.linspace (0,1e8, 10000)

legend = []

plt.plot(pwl_data[0],pwl_data[1])
plt.plot(spline_x,interpolate.splev(spline_x,pwl_spline ),'*')
legend.append("Data")
legend.append("Interpolated Data")

plt.xscale('log')
plt.legend(legend) 
plt.grid(True)
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The spline fitting have to be performed on the linearized data, i.e. using `log(x)` instead of `x`:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

#Original Data
pwl_data = np.array([[1, 1e3, 1e5, 1e8], [-90, -90, -90, -130]])

x = pwl_data[0]
y = pwl_data[1]

log_x = np.log(x)

#spine interpolation
pwl_spline = interpolate.splrep(log_x, y)

spline_log_x = np.linspace(0, 18, 30)
spline_y = interpolate.splev(spline_log_x, pwl_spline )

plt.plot(log_x, y, '-o')
plt.plot(spline_log_x, spline_y, '-*')
plt.xlabel('log(x)');
```

note: I remove the zero from the data. Also, spline fitting could be not the best if you want a piecewise linear function, you could have a look at this question for example: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/8457/53362

Answer (score 0):

For plotting with matplotlib, consider matplotlibs `step` which internally performs a piecewise constant interpolation.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html

you can invoke it simply via:

`plt.step(x,y)` given your inputs x and y.

In plotly the argument `line_shape='hv'` for the Scatter plot achieves similar results see https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/